# hwo can i find full path of dynamic library after find_package in cmake?

Tags: installation, cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project(vqdworker CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

FILE(GLOB SC_FILES "cpp source files ... ")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})


INSTALL(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}
                LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DIR}
    )
#INSTALL("hwo to copy opencv dynamic library to my installed path"
    )

camek ../myapp
make
```

it's work fine.
I want copy opencv dynamic library to my installed path use INSTALL(...).
Is there any way to find full path of dynamic library after find_package in cmake?

Comment: Isn't `OpenCV_LIBS` variable contain full paths?

Comment: i print the ${OpenCV_LIBS}, only filename.

Comment: any easy way do this? maybe OpenCV_DLLS :>